# Distinguishing between article pages and list/disambiguation pages in Wiki

Tags: python, wikipedia

I am generating random pages from Wikipedia using '[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aRandom)' and reading them using BeautifulSoup. The problem is that I only want article pages like :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_County,_Idaho

But sometimes it a list page or disambiguation page (which I don't want). e.g. : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._counties_named_after_personal_first_names

Is there an easy way to distinguish these cases?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the HTML generated for those cases? Do all list pages' `<title>` start "List of"? Could you search for "This disambiguation page lists articles associated with the same title." What have you done so far?

Comment: I am using the BeautifulSoup: 
        read_data = urllib2.urlopen(src).read()
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(read_data)
        s=""
        defination = self.soup.find_all('p')
Not HTML is involved

Comment: "Not [sic] HTML is involved"? What do you think `BeautifulSoup` is doing?

Comment: I know what it is doing. I just don't want to involve in direct business with HTML. Clear?

Comment: Moderately; does using BS to get the title element and checking how it starts count as too hands-on?

Answer (score 2):

Use [the API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) to tell if a page is disambiguation. E.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops&format=json&ppprop=disambiguation&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&grnlimit=10) will retrieve 10 random titles in article namespace ([try interactively in sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aApiSandbox#action=query&prop=pageprops&format=json&ppprop=disambiguation&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&grnlimit=10)). Disambiguation pages will have `"pageprops":{"disambiguation":""}` in their properties. Unfortunately, there's no such easy way for lists, you'll have to guess from their titles (`/^List of .*/`) or categories.

Answer (score 2):

List pages can (most of the times) be distinguished by querying WikiData for the value(s) of P31 ([instance of](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property%3aP31)). [List pages](http://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q678323) will have the value Q13406463 (Wikimedia List pages).

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q678323
```

If you are using this approach, you can check for disambiguation pages at the same time. These [will have](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q532508) the value Q4167410 ([Wikimedia disambiguation page](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q4167410)).

There are anumber of Python libraries for interacting with the MediaWiki API, e.g. [wikitools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikitools):

```
listOfTitles = 'Ada_County,_Idaho|List_of_U.S._counties_named_after_personal_first_names'

site = wikitools.Wiki("http://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php", user, password)
site.login(user,password)

params = {'action':'wbgetentities', 'props':'claims','titles':listOfTitles,'format':'json'}
request = wikitools.APIRequest(site, params)
result = request.query()
```